# Mark Node as Failed under graphlib TopologicalSorter

Tags: python, queue, graph-theory, python-3.9

From [`graphlib.TopologicalSorter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html#graphlib.TopologicalSorter), I can process nodes from a graph in parallel via:

```py
topological_sorter = TopologicalSorter()
topological_sorter.prepare()

while topological_sorter.is_active():
    for node in topological_sorter.get_ready():
        task_queue.put(node)

    node = finalized_tasks_queue.get()
    topological_sorter.done(node)
```

In my actual usecase, I have the `topological_sorter.done` conditioned on the status code of `node` like so:

```
if node.status_code == 0:
    topological_sorter.done(node)
```

0 represents success, and non-0 represents failure.

Given a node in a graph that depends on many other nodes, in the event that one of the dependees has a non-0 status code, I'd like `topological_sorter.is_active()` to return `False` (indicating that processing has went as far as possible).

However, the current behavior is that my `while` look will keep iterating, waiting for the last `done()` for a node with the non-0 status code to execute. Of course, that will never happen.

**Is there anyway to signal to `TopologicalSorter` that a node failed?** Each node would then eventually become the subject of a `done` call (processing succeeded), a `fail`-equivalent call (processing failed), or no call at all (processing went on forever).

Answer (score 1):

I built this functionality outside of graphlib. Graphlib is a very small module so you could probobly roll your own implementation. Basically my strategy is to keep track of the state outside of graphlib, and let it continue traversing the graph, but if a predeccessor node is in a failed state I dont actually let the work complete.

Essentially each of my nodes is an object, and has a state and a set of dependencies.

I'm doing my processing with a pattern like [Topological Sort With Threading Parallel Processing](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Python-graphlib-Topological-Sort/)

In my worker function I check the state of predecessor nodes. If any are failed, then I set the node to failed state. If its a failed state it just marks the node as done. Otherwise it runs the logic for the node. I catch any errors and mark the node as failed if the logic fails.

Comment: So you still do `topological_sorter.done(node)` on a failed `node`, but others nodes which have `node` as a dependency (via your external state) call `done` automatically without doing anything? If I understood right, that seems like a great solution.